# No module named 'pandas', 'mysql' despite both of the models are installed

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code as my main code editor while I'm compiling the code in multiple files it keeps giving me this error for multiple models for example

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I reinstall these two packages using `pip install pandas` and `pip install MySQL` on my cmd but both of them give me this message `requirement already satisfied` which mean that both of the two libraries are installed

ps I use `python 3.8.1 32-bit` as my main interpreter path on VS code

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: maybe it's as simple as restarting the IDE?

Comment: do you use virtual environments, which Python interpreter is selected, for which Python have you installed the modules

Comment: Use the terminal in VS code to install the packages?

Comment: @A.RahmanMahmoud i even try to reinstall the IDE

Comment: @rioV8 no im using vs in my local machine and the selected interpreter is python 3.8 not conda

Comment: @QuangHoang the same messages: requirement already satisfied

Comment: conda is not the only option, `venv` is build in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using virtual environment for your python project in the vscode, then you need to define the path of python(virtual environment) for your workspace.

So in your project, there is  `.vscode/setting.json` where you need to add following.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/project/project_name/bin/python"
}
```

After that you can restart your project.

Comment: no, I'm not using a virtual environment I'm using it on my local machine :/

Comment: Have you used ```venv``` while creating the project? Like in this docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html.  Also can you add you project tree in your question by running the command ```tree``` in your project directory.